# Specifying evaluation parameters for ExpectationConfiguration object in Great Expectations

Tags: python, great-expectations

I am trying to find out how to specify an evaluation parameter when I create an ExpectationConfiguration object.

To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

I have followed instructions as to how to create expectations using ExpectationConfiguration:

https://great-expectations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/how_to_guides/creating_and_editing_expectations/how_to_create_a_new_expectation_suite_without_a_sample_batch.html

I define the ExpectationConfiguration as follows:

```
 expectation_configuration_2 = ExpectationConfiguration(
       expectation_type="expect_column_distinct_values_to_be_in_set",
   kwargs = {
      "column" : "gameid",
      "value_set" : {"$PARAMETER" : "runtime_values"}
      },
   meta={
    "notes": {
    "format": "markdown",
    "content": "Ensures that certain values of gameid are included. **Markdown** `Supported`"
     }
 }
)
suite.add_expectation(expectation_configuration=expectation_configuration_2)
```

but I get this error:

```
great_expectations.exceptions.exceptions.EvaluationParameterError: No value found for $PARAMETER runtime_values
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version you can't run the expectation suite without checkpoint. You can pass evaluation parameters from checkpoints. And also you can provide default value for evaluation parameter in the suite itself.